# Excel macro with argument returns error "Cannot run the macro..."

Tags: excel, vba

I created a small macro-enabled excel worksheet, where I have several form buttons that increment a cell value.
This means I wanted to create a Sub with a String argument, being the cell in mention:

```
Sub increment_cell(cell As String)
  Range(cell).Value = Range(cell).Value + 1
End Sub
```

This worked fine, until I saved the book as an .xlsm file. I forgot to save the code for the macro, and rewrote it. Unfortunately, the button click now returns an error:

[image: Error returned when clicking button]

I assign the macro with `'increment_cell "XX"'`, with XX being the cell in mention, e.g. "A2". This results to `'dice-randomness-calculator.xlsm'!'increment_cell "XX"'` next time I open to look at assigned macros for the button

I have enabled macros in the settings:

[image: Macro settings]

I also tried creating a test-macro, without arguments, which works fine:

```
Sub increment()
  Range("N2").Value = Range("N2").Value + 1
End Sub
```

A picture of my code in Module1:

[image: VBA code]

I guess my question is, simplified, how do I create a macro that takes a string input for a button click? And more general, what am I doing wrong?

I am not used to coding in VBA, and I am slowly running out of ideas on how to debug this.

I did not want to use a spin button, as I never need to decrement, the buttons would be too small, and the risk of hitting a decrement when not needed was too big.

Comment: Do you try running the respective sub from **another workbook**? Please, better explain the context. **How do you call  (try calling) the sub in discussion** ? Which is the code in the assigned macro to the respective button?

Comment: Is there a relation between the cells and their corresponding `TopLeftCell` property of the buttons? If e.g. the cells are `A1`, `A2`, and `A3` and the corresponding buttons' top left cells are `B1`, `B2`, and `B3`, you could utilize `Application.Caller` in a single sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to assign the sub with parameter(s) to a button. You can bypass it with an intermediate sub assigned to the button.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
  increment_cell ("A1")
End Sub

Public Sub increment_cell(cell As String)
  Range(cell).Value = Range(cell).Value + 1
End Sub
```

So, assign Button1_Click to the button.
[image]

On this screenshot increment_cell and increment_cell1 are not enlisted to assign them to the button. Only suitable subs can be assigned.

Comment: But how did I get it to work before I saved the project as a .xlsm-file?

Comment: Have no idea. But if you "Assign macro..." for a button, Excel will show parameterless sus only.

Comment: The only way to get what you've got is to add a parameter to the sub after the sub was assigned. In this case Excell will alert "Argument not optional" when click on the button.

Comment: Well, I had hoped to create a single callable function, as I have 60 buttons. But I guess it's copy-paste for me :) Thanks for the quick answers

Answer (score 0):

You assignement is correct , but older excel version don't support assignements with argument (recent one like excel 2016 (version 2311) works)